# CentOS 7.3 repquota: Cannot stat() mounted device /dev/root: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, root, cpanel

I get an email that says this every day or so. Every search has come up with a solution that has not worked for me (apparently did work for CentOS 6.x)

Running cPanel on 
Linode
CENTOS 7.3 x86_64 kvm
WHM 60.0 (build 34)

Comment: What solutions have you tried that didn't work? Do you have any way to consistently reproduce the error?

Comment: @Heptite - I have tried symbolic links, and another thread said to create the directory, but that did nothing.